# For $Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, find $\mathbb{E}(Y^n)$ for odd and even $n$ using the expectation of $G\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

> For $\alpha,\beta>0$, the probability density function of a Gamma$(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable is given by
>   $$f(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta}}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x>0$$
>   For $\sigma>0$, the probability density function of a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variable is given by
>   $$f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Now for $G\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$, I have shown that for $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$
$$\mathbb{E}(G^k)=\frac{\beta^k\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}  \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
by manipulating the integrand $g^kf(g)$

> Let $Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, using the result $(1)$, or otherwise, show that for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$
>   $$\mathbb{E}(Y^n)=\ \begin{cases} 
>       \frac{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} & \text{n is even} \\
>      0 &\text{n is odd}  \\ 
>    \end{cases}
> $$

I decide to first tackle the odd case first, as this seemed most obvious.

**For odd $n$**
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y^n)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y^n\frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} dy=0
$$
as the integrand is an odd function when $n$ is odd.

For the even case, I have seen a solution that actually solved the expectation by definition. I wanted to use the result $(1)$, as I thought this could speed things up. But i'm unsure if my solution is valid.

**For even $n$**

We first start with 
\begin{align}
&Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2) \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{Y}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1) \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_1 \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\Big)\\
&\Rightarrow Y^2\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\sigma^2\Big) \\
\end{align}
Now let $$Z=Y^2\Rightarrow Y=Z^\frac{1}{2}$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}(Y^n)=\mathbb{E}(Z^{\frac{n}{2}})=\frac{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}$$

I am not entirely sure that my logic for the even case, where I derived a gamma distribution from the normal distribution, is correct. Is this a sufficient answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is the equality
$$Z = Y^2 \implies Y = Z^{1/2}$$
since due to that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ (i.e., $Y$ can take on negative values), it follows that
$$Z^{1/2} = \sqrt{Y^2} = |Y|\text{.}$$
Instead, take advantage of the following: since $Y^2 \sim \text{Gamma}\left( \dfrac{1}{2}, 2\sigma^2\right)$, you know that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ that
$$\mathbb{E}[(Y^2)^k] = \mathbb{E}[Y^{2k}] = \dfrac{(2\sigma^2)^{k}\Gamma(1/2+k)}{\Gamma(1/2)}$$
and we may set $n:= 2k$ (since $2k$ is obviously an even number) to obtain
$$\mathbb{E}[Y^n]=\dfrac{(2\sigma^2)^{n/2}\Gamma(1/2+n/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\text{.}$$
The reason why your answer coincides with this one is because
$$|Y|^n = Y^n$$
when $n$ is even.

Comment: Thnaks! If I can just ask as well, I was just having another look at this step \begin{align} &\Rightarrow \frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\Big)\\
&\Rightarrow Y^2\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\sigma^2\Big) \\
\end{align} and i don't quite understand how this is true. Doesn't $$cY\sim\text{Gamma}(a,cb) \ \ \text{for} \ \ Y\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)?$$ and hence shouldn't \begin{align}&\Rightarrow \frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\Big)\\
&\Rightarrow Y^2\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Big)?? \\
\end{align}

Comment: @Bell Since $\dfrac{Y^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \text{Gamma}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}, 2\right)$, it follows that $$\dfrac{Y^2}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sigma^2 = Y^2 \sim \text{Gamma}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}, 2\sigma^2\right)$$

Comment: Cool, thank you! If I can ask, what is the reason for this? For example, if $$X\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)$$ why does $$c\cdot X\sim\text{Gamma}(a,c\cdot b)$$ and why not $$c\cdot X\sim\text{Gamma}(c\cdot a,b)$$

Comment: @Bell How much do you know about finding PDFs of transformations? Let $Y = cX$. This means that $X = Y/c$, so you can use the formula $$f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(y/c) \cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}[y/c]\right|$$
and when you work out the details from here, you'll see why this is true.

Comment: @Bell Another way to do this would be to use the MGF of $X$ and the formula
$$M_{cX}(t) = M_{X}(ct) = \left[1-b(ct) \right]^{-\alpha} = \left[1-(bc)t \right]^{-\alpha}  $$
which is, indeed, the MGF of a $\text{Gamma}(a, bc)$ random variable.

Comment: This result for the MGF is very powerful. Do know where I can find some further reading on this? It is a result I saw in first/second year but have long forgotten. For this case, does it work because $$m_{cX}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{X(ct)})=m_X(ct)$$

Comment: I also have a query. If $$\frac{X}{c}\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)$$ then by the MGF method you stated above, doesn't $$m_{\frac{X}{c}}(u)=m_X\Big(\frac{u}{c}\Big)=\Big(1-b\Big(\frac{u}{c}\Big)\Big)^{-a}\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(a,\frac{b}{c}\Big)$$

Comment: @Bell Precisely, and yes, but note that (of course) $c$ has to be a constant, and of course, in all of our derivations, we've assumed $c > 0$.

Comment: @Bell Just get any standard probability textbook. I personally recommend Wackerly's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*.

Comment: Awesome, i'll give it a look!

Comment: Just to follow up, if we've established that $$\frac{X}{c}\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)\Rightarrow X\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(a,\frac{b}{c}\Big)$$ Then shouldn't $$\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},2\Big)\Rightarrow Y^2\sim\text{Gamma}\Big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Big)$$ Isn't $\sigma$ some constant?

Comment: @Bell No, [you've already asked about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838028/for-y-sim-n0-sigma2-find-mathbbeyn-for-odd-and-even-n-using-the/2838482?noredirect=1#comment5855510_2838482). Furthermore, your statement about $X$ isn't true.

Comment: Should I create a separate post on this? I am very confused.

Comment: @Bell I'm assuming you made a typo. That is, if $X/c \sim \text{Gamma}(a, b)$, then $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a, cb)$. Here's a very simple proof: observe that $X = X/c \cdot c$. Since $X/c \sim \text{Gamma}(a, b)$, it follows that $$M_{X/c \cdot c}(t) = M_{X/c}(ct) = [1-b(ct)]^{-\alpha} = [1-(bc)t]^{-\alpha}$$
so $X/c \cdot c = X \sim \text{Gamma}(a, bc)$, no contradiction there. If this still doesn't make any sense, create another question.

Comment: I completely agree with your working, I just don't know why my example doesn't work. Thank you for all your help. I have submitted a new question.